# How can the Model S have a three-phase motor? I thought it was DC?

Tags: batteries, induction-motor

Supposedly the [Tesla Model S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Model_S) has a three-phase AC induction motor.

I thought it ran on batteries. Aren't batteries DC?

Comment: They use variable frequency induction motor controllers. The controllers turn DC into variable frequency 3 phase AC.

Answer (score 4):

An industrial Variable Frequency Drive (VDF) takes AC turns it into DC and then back into AC. For cars such as the Tesla, they just skip the first step.

[image]

By taking in DC and pulsing it with 3 half bridges AC can be approximated.

Comment: First step isn't skipped. They do rectify AC on some stages: during charging or regeneration.